# How to write Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
      EnumID    EnumTypeID  EnumName    EnumParentID
        1       1            India         0
        2       2            Gujarat       1
        3       3            Ahmedabad     2
        4       3            Bhavnagar     2
        5       3            Botad         2
        6       3            Rajkot        2
        7       1            Australia     0
        8        2            abc           7
        9        3            adilade       8

Here EnumTypeID 1 indicate "Country"
                2 indicate "State"
                3 indicate "City"
```

Above is my database and i want the result like below

```
EnumID  Country State City 
  3      India  Gujarat Ahmedabad
  4      India  Gujarat Bhavnagar
  5      India  Gujarat Botad
  6      India  Gujarat Rajkot
  9      Australia abc  adilade
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use three levels of self-joins:

```
SELECT t3.EnumID AS EnumID, t1.EnumName AS Country, t2.EnumName AS State, t3.EnumName AS City
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t1.EnumID=t2.EnumParentID)
  INNER JOIN table t3 ON (t2.EnumID=t3.EnumParentID)
WHERE t1.EnumTypeID=1 AND t2.EnumTypeID=2 AND t3.EnumTypeID=3
```

Now, you know you may have inconsistent information in your table.  It is assumed that the second level is always EnumTypeID=2 and the third level is always EnumTypeID=3.  You may instead have wrong data that has a parent ID but EnumTypeID=1 (essentially a country within a country) etc.

When you have hierarchal data (i.e. data with a parent link) which also specifies the layer the record is in, the parent link and the layer number may be inconsistent.  In other words, you'll always need to make sure that parent.layer = child.layer - 1 if child.parent = parent.  Make sure your code does this check.

Comment: thanks stephen but it can not give actual result to which i looking for

Comment: What's wrong?  Any error message?  Is it a malformed SQL?  We don't have your database, so you may have to do **some** work here, you know!

Comment: nothing wrong with this i am not getting any error i got answer but 50% of my data is retrive from this query i got out put like below Country State City
India Gujarat Ahmedabad
India Gujarat Bhavnagar
India Gujarat Botad
India Gujarat Rajkot

Comment: Can you give an example of which few records that should be returned but not?  It would be good to give what you already see with this query.

Comment: Country State City
`India Gujarat Ahmedabad
India Gujarat Bhavnagar
India Gujarat Botad
India Gujarat Rajkot`

Comment: @user350104, you got to learn to be more precise.  Is that your *expected* result that is *missing*, or all the results (and it is missing certain rows)?  If it is missing certain rows, what are those rows?  And how are they represented in the database?

Comment: i already mention those rows in my question which i want as out put

Comment: What do you get now?  Nothing?  Or something else?  When asking questions always put: (1) expected output, (2) actual output, (3) input data.

Comment: Thanks stephen i got my answer with slight change on query t3.EnumID give me the proper output

Comment: Oh.  I see it now.  EnumID of your desired result is the ID for the *city*, not the *country*.  I'll edit my answer.  See, you figured it out yourself.  Welcome to the fun world of programming and debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Select all field which you want and order by city as records coming in ascending or descending wise as ASC or DESC

```
Select EnumID,Country,State,City  From TableName Order by City  Asc
```

(asending order)
    Select EnumID,Country,State,City  From TableName Order by City  Desc
(descending order)

Comment: This is not what he wants - the table does not contain the columns Country, State or City. They are rolled up into the columns: EnumTypeId and EnumName